# Trying to convert elements of a string into numbers based on position of character in alphabet

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to take the string `char theString[256] = "BreakfastLunchDinner";` and covert each character into a number based on its position in the alphabet, i.e. B = 2, f = 6, l = 12, etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
void main()
{
    char theString[256] = "BreakfastLunchDinner";
}

void firstLast(char theString[], char *first, char *last)
{
    int i = 0;
    int num[256];

    while(theString != '\0')
    {
            if(theString[i] >= 'A' && theString[i] <= 'Z')
            {
            num[i] = theString[i] - 'A';
            }
            else if(theString[i] >= 'a' && theString[i] <= 'z')
            {
            num[i] = theString[i] - 'a';
            }
            i++;
    }
}
```

I've included the declaration in the main function to try and be as detailed as possible, the pointers are for later use, and I'm currently focusing on the conversion aspect explained above. When I try to run the "firstLast" function in a separate program on its own I get segmentation fault core dumped from the compiler. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You say "B = 2" so you would need `num[i] = theString[i] - 'A' + 1;` and it only works for consecutive alphabet encoding, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @WeatherVane: All hail EBCDIC!

Comment: @ScottHunter that was just for you!

Comment: @WeatherVane What would be a better more consistent method in that case? For the conversion.

Comment: You can prepare a look-up table, with the letter as the index. `int lookup[256] = { /*... some values ...*/ 1, 2, 3, 4, /* etc */ };` and then `value = lookup[ theString[i] ];` but you must make sure the `char` is `unsigned` for values > `0x7F`.

Comment: The seg-fault issue is probably a typo so voting to close, but the conversion could be simplified by:  `num[i] = std::toupper(theString[i]) - 'A' + 1 ;`

Comment: @Clifford, The question references C, not C++ and in C, a statement like: `std::toupper()` does not exit

Comment: @user3629249 Your point is well made. I was in a C++ mindset.  The comment applies nonetheless presuming it is not beyond the wit of the OP to remove the std::.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `theString` never changes, the loop will never terminate, and `theString[i]` probably ventured off somewhere it isn't supposed to go, resulting in the segfault.

Your test should be `theString[i] != '\0'`.